# Append blade file to jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append, laravel-blade

IS there any way to achieve this:

```
<script>
    $('#appends').append('<div class="content-section" id="services">' + 
    " @include('visitor.pages.services') " + 
    ' </div>');
</script>
```

What i want is to append the content of `visitor.pages.services` to `#appends` div

`visitor.pages.services` is not a php url or something. It is just some lines of html where i am including in my main page.

this is the file

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="heading-section col-md-12 text-center">
            <h2>Our Services</h2>
            <p>We design mobile-first websites for you</p>
        </div> <!-- /.heading-section -->
    </div> <!-- /.row -->
    <div class="row">
        @foreach($data['services'] as $service)
            ... bla bla
        @endforeach
    </div> <!-- /.row -->
</div> <!-- /.container -->
```

Comment: You need to include more info about 'visitor.pages.services' if Loading..'s answer didn't fix your problem.

Comment: @Andrew I fixed the problem by creating a url for this partial. btw i am in Laravel. Now i have another problem in passing $data['services']. If you have some idea please share :)

Comment: Actually i fixed it all. Thanks a lot :)))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As your question says, you want to get the content of the file and append it to the specific element.

Use **`$.get()`**

```
$.get("visitor.pages.service.html", function(data){
    $('#appends').append(data);
});
```

**OR `.load()`**

```
$('#appends').append( $('<div>').load('visitor.pages.service.html'));
```

**OR `.ajax()`**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "your.html",
    success: function (data) { $('#appends').append(data); },
    dataType: 'html'
});
```

Comment: Hey Loadin.. thanks for helping. It is just that my data is not a url content. Is justs lins of php file that i am including in my main page. What i want is to append those php lines when i want to

Comment: @Iraklis if you want to get the data from server (php) in client (jquery), you need to use `$.ajax()` to get the data from PHP.

Comment: If i do what you are saying correctly, i will get all the data of my main page and not only the partial data that i want. If i 'get' the data url i wil be forced to get all the data of main page and not only the services. Am I  right?

Comment: I cannot isolate the visitor.pages.services because it is not url it is just a 'partial' of my main view

Comment: I fixed the problem by making a route in Laravel. Now i have problem passing $data['services']. If you have some idea please edit your answer! Thanks!

Comment: Actually i fixed it all. Thanks a lot :)))