# Append/Add Laravel blade template to current view using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade

So, I have this:

`item.blade.php`(locaton: 'pages/components/item.blade.php')

```
<div>
 // some php logic
test
</div>
```

`list.blade.php`

```
// some laravel blade logic

<script>
    function onAddItem() {

// the code above doesn't work
        $.get("visitor.pages.service.html", function(data){
           $('#appends').append(data);
        });
      }
    }

</script>


<div>
  <button onclick="onAddItem()">add item</button>

  <div id="list">
    @include('pages.components.item', ['someVars'=> false]); //this displays OK
  </div>

</div>
```

Now what I wanna do is when I click the add item button, it should also add another `pages.components.item` template inside `list` (id) div.

I already tried the answers on these posts:

- [Appending Laravel Blade from JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37089795/2784493)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/40219813/2784493

But both answers don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the answer pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37089905/8555937) you can't do that, as blade is server side processed. There is a workaround however but it's expensive and prone to vulnerabilities: create custom routes which output the desired blade files when needed.

In `routes.php`:

```
Route::get('/blades/{path_to_blade}', function($path_to_blade){
    return view($path_to_blade);
})->where('path_to_blade', '^[a-z0-9\_\-\.]+$');
```

Then you can use an ajax call or whatever to call the requested template. I'm using jQuery as demo:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/blades/template.path",
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
        $("#element_in_which_to_insert").append(html);
    }
});
```

You can also request the template in browser: `/blades/template.path`. **But again:** this method is prone to vulnerabilities. You should use a frontend framework such as Vue or Angular instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

`function onAddInvoiceItem()`

not

`function addItem()`

Because you call it with `onAddInvoiceItem()` here :

```
<button onclick="onAddInvoiceItem()">add item</button>
```

Comment: oops my bad, but its the same, I just forgot to rename the other one when putting it here.